# Adding padding to Powershell window (just as in CSS)?

Tags: powershell, styles

The output in Powershell is totally juxtaposed to the screen.

Do you know a way to give it some left padding so to push it a bit more towards the vertical midline just as you give `#some_id {padding-left: 5px}` in CSS?

I've found this article describing some manipulation with DOT.net code but I'm not familiar with this language it all and can't try that.

If I'm not wrong, the solution should be in XML/XSL or some conf format? I am glad of asking this: An answer could give data to many users both on this Powershell issue and on customizing the markup/stylesheet of a program for personal comparability.

[image]

Comment: where did you read this? I don't think there is a padding option for PowerShell console yet.

Comment: I didn't read about this but I did thought to myself about manipulating the markup somehow, most probably by tweaking the XML or the XSL stylesheet (if there is one).

Comment: BTW, do you think they built the Powershell markup with XML and it's basic design with XSL (IINW, as with many other local programs) ? Thank you.